# Which is a more optimal Firestore schema for getting a Social Media feed?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm toying with several ideas for using Firestore for a social media feed. So far, the ideas I've had haven't panned out, so for this one I'm hoping to get the community's feedback.

The idea is to allow users to post information, or to record their activity, and to any user following/subscribed to that information, display it. The posts information would be in a root collection called `posts`.

The approaches, as far as I can tell, require roughly the same number of reads and writes.

One idea is to have within the `users/{userId}` have a field called posts which is an array of documentIds that I'm interested in pulling for the user. This would allow me to pull directly from `posts` and get the most up-to-date version of the data.

Another approach seems more Firebasey which is to store documents within users/{userId}/feeds that are copies of the posts themselves. I can use the same `postID` as the data in `posts`. Presumably, if I need to update the data for any review, I can use a group collection query to get all collections called feeds, where the docID is equal (or just create a field to do a proper `"where", "==", docId`).

Third approach is all about updating the list of people who should view the posts. This seems better as long as the list of posts is shorter than the lists of followers. Instead of maintaining all posts on every follower, you're maintaining all followers on each post. For every new follower, you need to update all posts.

This list would not be a user's own posts. Instead it would be a list of all the posts to show that user.

***Three challengers:***

1. users/{userId} with field called `feed` - an array of doc Ids that point to the global posts. Get that feed, get all docs by ID. Every array would need to be updated for every single follower each time a user has activity.

   ```
   users (coll)
       -> uid (doc)
       -> uid.feed: postId1, postId2, postId3, ...] (field)

   posts (coll)
       -> postId (doc)
   ```

Query (pseudo):

```
doc(users/{uid}).get(doc)
    feed = doc.feed
    for postId in feed:
        doc(posts/{postId}).get(doc)
```

2. users/{userId}/feed which has a copy of all `posts` that you would want this user to see. Every activity/post would need to be added to every relevant feed list.

   ```
   users (coll)
       -> uid (doc)
            -> feed: (coll)
                  -> postId1 (doc)
                  -> postId2
                  -> postId3

   posts (coll)
       -> postId (doc)
   ```

Query (pseudo):

```
collection(users/{uid}/feed).get(docs)
    for post in docs:
        doc(posts/{post}).get(doc)
```

3. users/{userId}/feed which has a copy of all `posts` that you would want this user to see. Every activity/post would need to be added to every relevant feed list.

   ```
   users (coll)
       -> uid (doc)


   posts (coll)
       -> postId (doc)
       -> postId.followers_array[followerId, followerId2, ...] (field)
   ```

Query (pseudo):

```
collection(posts).where(followers, 'array_contains', uid).get(docs)
```

***Reads/Writes***

**1. Updating the Data**
For the author `user` of every activity, find all users following that 
user. Currently, the users are stored as documents in a collection, so this is followerNumber document reads. For each of the users, update their array by prepending the `postId` this would be followerNumber document writes.

**1. Displaying the Data/Feed**
For each fetch of the feed: get array from user document (1 doc read). For each postId, call, `posts/{postId}`

This would be numberOfPostsCalled document reads.

**2. Updating the Data**
For the author `user` of every activity, find all users following that 
user. Currently, the users are stored as documents in a collection, so this is followerNumber document reads. For each of the users, add a new document with ID `postId` to `users/{userId}/feed` this would be followerNumber document writes.

**2. Displaying the Data/Feed**
For each fetch of the feed: get a certain number of posts from `users/{userId}/feed`

This would be numberOfPostsCalled document reads.

This second approach requires me to keep all of the documents up to date in the event of an edit. So despite this approach seeming more firebase-esque, the approach of holding a `postId` and fetching that directly seems slightly more logical.

**3. Updating the Data**
For every new follower, each post authored by the person being followed needs to be updated. The new follower is appended to an array called followers.

**3. Displaying the Data**
For each fetch of the feed: get a certain number of posts from `posts` where `uid == viewerUid`

Comment: I'm really down to discuss this but I'm a visual person, would you mind to make samples of your schemas and the queries you havent done that failed?

Comment: What's the best visual you have in mind? Do you just mean a table layout of the schema? Happy to!

Comment: yeah, that would be good enough, also the queries you have tried :)

Comment: Hey @andresmijares I've just added a visual as well as a 3rd approach. I actually like the 3rd approach but I can see how maintaining all posts can become burdensome. The fetch for all posts is a less complex query, not sure if it pays off though.

Comment: Beautiful! Let me see!

Comment: I only added the displaying part, I think it's easier to read than to look at the schema for uploading the data. I put 3. Updating the Data for the 3 approaches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194786/discussion-between-dan-fein-and-andresmijares).

Answer (score 1):

Nice, when I talk about what is more optimal I really need a point or a quality attribute to compare, I' will assume you care about speed (not necessary performance) and costs.

This is how I would solve the problem, it involves several collections but my goal is 1 query only.

user (col)

```
{
 "abc": {},
 "qwe": {}
}
```

posts (col)

```
{
  "123": {},
  "456": {}
}
```

users_posts (col)

```
{
  "abc": {
    "posts_ids": ["123"]
  }
}
```

So far so good, the problem is, I need to do several queries to get all the posts information... This is where cloud functions get into the game. You can create a 4th collection where you can pre-calculate your feed

users_dashboard

```
{
  "abc": {
    posts: [
    {
       id: "123", /.../
    }, {
       id: "456", /.../
     }
    ]
  }
}
```

The cloud function would look like this:

```
/* on your front end you can manage the add or delete ids from user posts */
export const calculateDashboard = functions.firestore.document(`users_posts/{doc}).onWrite(async(change, _context) {
   const firestore = admin.firestore()
   const dashboardRef = firestore.collection(`users_dashboard`)
   const postRef = firestore.collection(`posts`)

   const user = change.after.data()
   const payload = []
   for (const postId of user.posts_ids) {
      const data = await postRef.doc(postId).get().then((doc) => doc.exists ? doc.data() : null)
      payload.push(data)
   }
   // Maybe you want to exponse only certain props... you can do that here
   return dashboardRef.doc(user.id).set(payload) 
})
```

The doc max size is `1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)` that is plenty of data you can store in, so you can have like a lot of posts here. Let's talk about costs; I used to think firestore was more like to have several small docs but I've found in practice it works equally well with big size into a big amount of docs.

Now on your dashboard you only need query:

```
const dashboard = firestore.collection(`users_dashboard`).doc(userID).get()
```

This a very opinionated way to solve this problem. You could avoid using the `users_posts`, but maybe you dont want to trigger this process for other than posts related changes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Andres. In an attempt to summarize, this would need to update for every every follower of a user, right? So in the event that user A follows user B, user A's dashboard needs to be updated to incorporate user B's posts. As well as for every post by a user user A is following. So user C makes a post, all of user C's follower's feeds need to be updated. I'm trying to optimize for both speed and cost, emphasis on cost right now so minimizing writes and reads. This approach seems doable, seems like a combination fo approaches #1 and #2 from above.

Comment: Yes sir, that's correct, It's better to do this on a cloud function, so the user doesnt have to pay for this and it's way cheap :)

Comment: I'd imagine updating the posts is something like collection('users_dashboard').where(post.postID == postId) then can you update just a single element in an array of maps? Do you think the number of writes is optimized here, with all those updates for each new post + follower? Thanks a ton by the way!

Comment: yeah that could work, to be honest, dont worry about the number of writes, you are making only a couple, you are going to do a lot of reads instead, i've been working with this approach in production for a like a year with collections of more than 90K records... my invoice is less than 10 usd ‍♂️, optimize for the user first, than make any arrangement you need later

Comment: One clarification point: the purpose of user_posts is to be an intermediary between who a user is following and making sure users_dashboard is updated right? I can look for a new post and then get all followers for the author of that post, then generate all of those users' feeds by prepending the data to their feeds.posts array? This all makes sense, also optimizing for user first is great advice

Comment: Yeah, the only use of that collection is not to trigger the functions for update on that user that are not related to the posts

Comment: You got it, just selected. Thanks again

Comment: lol what happened here? any reason to unaccept the answer @DanFein ?

Comment: While it's a good answer, for any future users it's not the best answer since the 1MB limit would not be something you hope to stay under but instead aim to not ever have to think about because you've gone with a better approach. I think the better approach is to just store all data as complete post documents and update them as necessary. So the final structure is something like /userId/posts/{postId} where postId is a common post, but a full document. Each user just pulls their own feed from there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your second approach is best in this situation.. I don't really understand what @andresmijares was trying to do and he mentioned something like storing posts in a document which is not a good approach, imagine if you have more than 20K posts (which what I think a document can hold) then the document won't be able to store any more data.. a better approach is to store posts as a document inside a Collection (just like in your 2nd option).. So let's recall here what's the best approach.

1)_ You share a post in the (posts "Collection") and in users you're following's (Feed "Collection").. maybe this can be done with cloud function and let's not forget to aggregate (with cloud functions also) the number of posts that needs to appear in the user's profile.

2)_ You follow a user and get all of their posts from the (posts "Collection") into your (Feed "Collection") this way you get to see all of their posts on your feed.

with this approach, there will be a lot of writes once but the read will be fast.. and if your app is about reading more and writing less then there's nothing to worry about unless i'm wrong.

Comment: I went closer to this direction than Andres'. Storing in a document made little sense in practice. So what I did was just make a document in a collection called feeds for every post for every user that the user is following. Much easier to handle. Get latest feed is simple by like limit(10)

Comment: @DanFein Did you handle it cloud side or front side ?? and if it's cloud side, how does the function look like?

Comment: Cloud side. I look for this:   exports.userFollowed =  functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}/following/{otherUserId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

and if I see that, I grab the last 10 posts and batch write them to feedsRef.doc(`${userId}/posts/${postId}`) which is basically just a feeds collection for each user.

Comment: So if a user has 1000 followers, you will be creating the document 1001 times? I'm not sure this makes sense either. It also would make updating a post difficult since you have to do it in all 1001 spots

Comment: As it turned out, Firestore is not the best option when it comes to “a social network” db. I went with a graph database.