# Firestore get for any value that matches item in array of values

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing a little bit of a mental block in terms of how to do some relational queries with firestore while adhering to the best practices. I am creating a feed feature where you can see a feed of posts from your friends. Essentially my data structure is as follows:

```
Friends (collection)
-friend_doc
  ...data
  friends_uid: [uid1, uid2]

Posts (collection)
-post_doc
  ...data
  posted_by: uid2
```

Basically I am making a query to get all of the friends where the *friends_uid* contains my uid (uid1 in this case). And then once I mapped all of the friends uid's to an array, I want to make a firestore query to get posts where the *posted_by* field is equal to any of the uid's in that array of friends uid's. I haven't been able to make something that does anything like that yet.

I know that it seems most convenient to loop through the string array of friends uid's and make a query for each one like:

```
  listOfUids.forEach(async (item) => {
    const postQuerySnapshot = await firestore()
      .collection('posts')
      .where('uid', '==', item)
      .get();
    results.push(postQuerySnapshot.docs);
  });
```

but this is extremely problematic for paging and limiting data as I could possibly receive tons of posts.  I may just be too deep into this code and missing an obvious solution or maybe my data structure is somewhat flawed. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who is looking on how to implement a similar "feed" type feature in firestore here is how I ended up tackling it:

I added a ***users_feed*** collection to my data structure as well as the posts collection and dealt with generating the feed inside of cloud functions. The users_feed collection acts as an intermediary so that the client-side only needs to pull data from that instead of generating a feed. **All the heavy lifting happens in the cloud functions**.

In the cloud functions whenever a post was made (onCreate) or updated (onUpdate) it would get the friends list of whoever made that post and write it to all of their feeds inside he users_feed collection using batched writes.

I found this other article which was super useful in coming up with the structure: [Which is a more optimal Firestore schema for getting a Social Media feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551404/which-is-a-more-optimal-firestore-schema-for-getting-a-social-media-feed)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for an `in` condition. With that you can pass up to 10 values, and it will return all documents where the field matches any of those values.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [in queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any).

If you have more than 10 UIDs, you'll have to still do multiple queries and merge the results client-side.